# Clojure: nullpointerexception with recursion

Tags: recursion, clojure, nullpointerexception

I am creating an overloaded function that takes a list of numbers as a parameter (as well as a list of numbers and a single number in the overloaded signature). From this list the highest value must be found and returned. I am aware of the available "sort" method which automatically sorts the list for you but I am attempting to discover the highest value using recursion. Below is the code I am working with.

```
32    (defn my-max
33      ([list]
34        (if (empty? list)
35          -1
36          (my-max (pop list) (first list))) ; recursive call
37        )
38      ([list high]
39        (if (empty? list) ; base case
40          high)
41        (if (> (first list) high)
42          (my-max (pop list) (first list)))
43        (my-max (pop list) high))
44      )
45    
46    (println (my-max '(1 2 3)))
```

As you can see, I have hard-coded a list containing 1, 2, and 3 for which 3 should be returned. when running the code I receive an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at clojure.lang.Numbers.ops(Numbers.java:942)
    at clojure.lang.Numbers.gt(Numbers.java:227)
    at user$my_max.invoke(HelloWorld.clj:41)
    at user$my_max.invoke(HelloWorld.clj:42)
    at user$my_max.invoke(HelloWorld.clj:42)
    at user$my_max.invoke(HelloWorld.clj:36)
    at user$eval2.invoke(HelloWorld.clj:46)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7020)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:294)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:356)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:440)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:415)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

This error occurs on the final recursive call where 3 has been "popped" from the list and is passed back to my-max as "high" the list is empty and:

```
(if (empty? list) ; line 39, base case
```

should evaluate true but is instead evaluating as false. Do you have any thoughts/solutions on this problem?

Comment: Arthur Ulfeldt's answer pointed out that there were misplaced parentheses.   Diego Basch's answer clarified how that problem led to the null pointer exception.  I just wanted to point out that paying attention to proper automatic indenting (which the code in your question illustrates), can make it immediately obvious that something is wrong with parentheses, since the expressions that are supposed to be *else* clauses are indented to exactly the same level as the initial `(if`'s.

Comment: Since you mention `sort` as a way to find the maximum in a list of numbers (not really efficient), be aware of [max](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/max) in clojure.core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `<` function can only compare numbers so a very straightforward approach is to use an `or` to ensure they are numbers. Also the second and third if statements had the closing ) in the wrong spots.

```
user> (defn my-max
       ([list]
         (if (empty? list)
          -1
           (my-max (pop list) (first list))))

       ([list high]
        (if (empty? list) ; base case
          high
         (if (> (or (first list) 0) (or high 0))
            (my-max (pop list) (first list))
            (my-max (pop list) high)))))
      #'user/my-max
      user> (println (my-max '(1 2 3)))
      3
      nil
```

Answer (score 6):

That statement (line 39-40) does nothing. No matter what it evaluates to (either `high` or `nil`), the value is not used. Then line 41 evaluates, and `(first list)` is nil if your list is empty, hence the null pointer exception.

Comment: In addition to the importance of using correct code indentation (and I'd recommend an editor which supports working with s-exp and balanced parens etc), it should also be noted that you should use recur rather than just calling your procedure recursively as Clojure does not have tail call optimisation. Recur will ensure that this function will work with even large lists where the current version will blow out the stack quite quickly